# How to add a slicer for count in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I was wondering if it is possible to add a slicer to show the count of rows in Power BI? I have some visuals/tables based on a set of filters (slicers) and I would like to add count as well and ignore data below a certain threshold by slicer. Lets say I have a dataset with some filters applied. I wasnt to see the row count of column with more than 2 data. In this example I should only get the result for column B as it comes with 3 data while column A has only 1 value.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add an index column and select index from slicer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Ashok! I updated my question with a screenshot of an example to clarify further what I'm looking for. Basically, adding index won't help that much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use countrows of table as filter, here steps:

**1. Create CountRows measure:**

```
CountRows = COUNTROWS('Data Table')
```

**2. Create Parameter under Modeling:**

1)choose Numeric range in New parameter under Modeling:

[image]

2)keep this page with dynamic values then click Create:

[image]

3)get one table named "Parameter", click **[Parameter] column** and change the medium number into [CountRows] measure:

[image]

**3. Create values measure based on your data table:**

```
Values under N countrows = 
IF(COUNTROWS('Data Table')>=[Parameter Value],
SUM('Data Table'[Value]),BLANK())
```

> Data table with Product countrows in A 1, B 2, C 3, D 4 respectively:

[image]

> Outcome with slicer:

[image]